# get regex value conditional search

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing 'velocity' values using regex.

I am able to do that when both values are present in group - actual values and given values (shown in ex 1). But when the value of velocity is not present in 'actual value', and only in 'given value'.

My regex is taking value from that.!

How can I add a a default value if the value is not present in 'actual value' and end the search before the new line starts.

```
actual values[\w\W]*?[vV]elocity XYZ\D+ [\w\W]*?(.+)
```

Ex. 1:

The regex works perfectly and give me all the groups.

```
----- actual values
 Machine XYZ [mm]:                        855.7766    -2578.3709    -1001.7072
 velocity XYZ [mm]:                      -.0002         .2765         .0050

----- given values
 Machine XYZ [mm]:             855.7745    -2580.1412    -1001.7041
 velocity XYZ [mm/s]:          -.0522      -60.0000         .0648
```

Ex. 2:

The regex parse the value from given values although I don't have any velocity in the actual values.

```
----- actual values
 Machine XYZ [mm]:                        855.7766    -2578.3709    -1001.7072
 val XYZ [mm]:              -.0002         .2765         .0050

----- given values
 Machine XYZ [mm]:             855.7745    -2580.1412    -1001.7041
 velocity XYZ [mm/s]:          -.0522      -60.0000         .0648
```

Comment: You may introduce any default values in the code, not in the regex.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/UtgyW6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the next lines are not an empty line or starts with `velocity` using a negative lookahead `(?!`

```
\bactual values.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\t]*(?:[Vv]elocity|$)).*)*\r?\n.*[vV]elocity XYZ[^\d\r\n]+(.*)
```

- `\bactual values.*` Match actual values and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `[^\S\r\t]*(?:[Vv]elocity|$)` Match 0+ whitespaces without a newline and match either velocity or the end of the string
  - `)` Close negative lookahead
  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n.*` Match a newline any char except a newline 0+times
- `[vV]elocity XYZ[^\d\r\n]+` match `velocity XYZ` and 1+ times not a digit or a newline
- `(.*)` Capture group 1, match any char except a newline 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCGV9w/1)

You might also be more specific and match the digits in group 1 instead of using `.*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sz0EgZ/1)